# Key/value pairs should be last arguments? Syntax error in users controller Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following in my controller

```
@user_party = UserParty.request(:start_date => params[:start_date], :start_time => params[:start_time]), current_user, @friend)
```

however I get the error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting => ...ams[:start_time], current_user, @friend) ... ^

My full controller is

```
def create
    if params[:user_party] && params[:user_].has_key?(:friend_id)
        @friend = User.find(params[:user_party][:friend_id])
        @user_party = Userparty.request({:start_date => params[:start_date], :start_time => params[:start_time]}, current_user, @friend)
            respond_to do |format|
                if @user_party.new_record?
                    format.html do
                        flash[:error] = "There was a problem creating that friend request." 
                        redirect_to user_path(@friend)
                    end
                    format.json {render json: @user_party.to_json}

                else        
                    format.html do
                        flash[:success] = "Userparty request sent"
                        redirect_to user_path(@friend)
                    end
                    format.json {render json: @user_party.to_json}
                end
            end 


    else
        flash[:error] = "party required"
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end
```

and my user_party.rb is like so

```
def self.request(start_date, start_time, user1, user2)
transaction do

    party1 = UserParty.create!(start_date: start_date, start_time: start_time, user: user1, friend: user2, state: 'pending')

    party2 = UserParty.create!(start_date: start_date, start_time: start_time, user: user2, friend: user1, state: 'requested' )


end
```

end

How would you write this properly? Thanks in advance

Comment: This is why having hash-style options at the end is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write as

```
@user_party = UserParty.request({:start_date => params[:start_date], :start_time => params[:start_time]}, current_user, @friend)
```

You can pass the key/value pairs as a comma separated list

- while there are no other kind of arguments.
- while there are other kind of arguments, key/value pairs should be last arguments.

So:

```
def foo(options = {})
  p options
end

foo(1=>2, 2=>3)
# => {1=>2, 2=>3}

def bar(a,options = {})
  p options
end

bar(11, 1=>2, 2=>3)
# => {1=>2, 2=>3}
```

Now, while none of the above case holds -

```
def bar(options = {},a)
  p options
end
bar(1=>2,3=>4,12)
# SyntaxError: (irb):12: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting =>'
```

Looking at your original method definition, call should be:

```
Userparty.request(params[:start_date], params[:start_time]}, current_user, @friend)
```

Comment: I don't why code formatting is not working. Any help please ?

Comment: @user3736107 I am not seeing your method signature.. show us then that please.

Comment: Added a little text to get the code formatter to settle down.

Comment: @tadman I see. I tried a lot, no luck!.. Thank you very much!

Comment: I put the key/value pairs as the last argument and it still doesn't work